# Stop duplicating markers while using leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a problem with my code. I want to have a routing being updating when the user moves. It works because im using "watchPosition" but when the user moves. It creates an another marker on the map. How to stop that ?

here is my code :

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var map = L.map('map');
            map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

            //Getting Map
            L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            }).addTo(map);

            //Geolocalisation
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(get);

            let marker, circle, zoomed;

            function success(pos) {
                const lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                const lng = pos.coords.longitude;
                const accuracy = pos.coords.accuracy;
                const getFixedPosition = $(".getfixed");

                if (marker) {
                    map.removeLayer(marker);
                    map.removeLayer(circle);
                }

                marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {
                    title: "Votre Position actuelle",
                    // icon: customIcon
                }).bindPopup("<h3>Votre position</h3>").addTo(map);

                circle = L.circle([lat, lng], {
                    radius: accuracy
                }).addTo(map);

                if (!zoomed) {
                    zoomed = map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
                }

                map.setView([lat, lng]);
                $("#displayLong").val(lng);
                $("#displayLat").val(lat);
                $("#displayAccu").val(accuracy);

                const lng_client = $("#displayLongClient").val();
                const lat_client = $("#displayLatClient").val();
                const accuracy_client = $("#displayAccuClient").val();

                var justToday = new Date();
                var getjustToday = justToday.toLocaleString();

                **if (lng_client != null && lat_client != null && accuracy_client != null) {
                    L.Routing.control({
                        waypoints: [
                            L.latLng(lat, lng), //position of the user
                            L.latLng(lat_client, lng_client) //arrival point
                        ]
                    }).addTo(map);**
                }

            }


            function get(current_position) {
                $('.myPosition input[name="inputLat"]').val(current_position.coords.latitude);
                $('.myPosition input[name="inputLong"]').val(current_position.coords.longitude);
                $('.myPosition input[name="inputAccu"]').val(current_position.coords.accuracy);
            }

            function error(err) {
                if (err.code === 1) {
                    alert("activez la geolocalisation s'il vous plait");
                }
            }
        });
```

I dont think the html will be useful here. I put the main problem in two group of stars(** **). Thank you !

Comment: can you provide the snippet?

Comment: yes i think i already gave the code source. The main problem is the `L.Routing.control`